# How do i keep dart names (variables, constants, objects ) using dart2js commands?

Tags: build, compilation, dart, dart-pub, dart2js

I'm trying to compile a dart project by using the command

```
pub build
```

However, this will generate random identifiers for all objects, which will ruin all logging information when it prints the object name.

For example, "Object = K1" is printed instead of "Object = Mirror".

Is there a way to keep all dart names, while compiling to `.js`?

I also tried:

```
pub build --mode=debug
```

...but the downside is that for production builds, debug mode is now allowed.

Is there any production build approach for this issue?

Comment: Why do you need to log in production mode? It should be the final phase of your working code, there should be no need for you to debug. That's what debug mode is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable minification in pubspec.yaml:

```
transformers:
- $dart2js:
  minify: false
```

See [here](https://webdev.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dart2js-transformer) for more details about the pub transformer.